# Search for every line containing 'X' then replace the fourth element Regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have several tables that I'm trying to update. I need to update the fourth element of each table, when the first element matches a certain string.

Example table (in Lua):

```lua
TABLE = {

{TEXT1,0,4,0,0,0,0},
{TEXT2,0,4,0,0,0,0},
{TEXT3,0,5,0,0,0,0},
{TEXT1,0,5,0,0,0,0},
{TEXT1,0,4,0,0,0,0},
{TEXT4,0,5,0,0,0,0}

}
```

I can use the following to select only tables that have the element "TEXT1":

```
(?=TEXT1)
```

I can also use the following statement to select the content in between the fourth and fifth comma:

```
^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,\K(.*?)(?=,\d)
```

I can't figure out how to use both expressions at once though.

So basically, I'd like to replace `0` in every table that starts with the string "TEXT1", but how do I combine my statements to check for the required text, then select the fourth element in that table only?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `^\{TEXT1,([^,]+,){3}\K[^,]+` to select the element you are after and then replace it by whatever you like. Replacing by `999` would turn your table into

```
TABLE = {

{TEXT1,0,4,0,999,0,0},
{TEXT2,0,4,0,0,0,0},
{TEXT3,0,5,0,0,0,0},
{TEXT1,0,5,0,999,0,0},
{TEXT1,0,4,0,999,0,0},
{TEXT4,0,5,0,0,0,0}

}
```

Note that in your title ask for the fourth element, but your regex selects the element betweeen fourth and fifth comma - which is the fifth element and used here. Also note that you might want to replace `[^,]` by `[^,\n\r]` if the table could contain less than six elements at any place.

Comment: Very good answer (+1) - does `notepad++` support `\K` though?

Comment: @Jan yes, it does.